# Help me to build some devices for measuring LEDs optical power[mW] with range (1 -100)mW included

Tags: led, optics

I have an application of photoactivation device with 10-20 LEDs for every color;  with the following wavelengths : red 630-670nm ;yellow 575-595nm , green 510-540nm .
 In order to obtain an  uniform light I have to use diffuser-placed at certain distance, so the optical power from data sheet will be changed. So I need to build or buy (under 80 dollars) a device for measuring optical power [mW] of LEDs .
 I hope this will be quite simple question, I hope to obtain a real help this time.

Comment: It would be helpful to narrow this to a single, clear question about electronics design.

Comment: Purchase questions are off-topic, this question is barely even coherent, and "color therapy" is pseudoscientific bullshit. Vote to close.

Comment: Color therapy (using LED s, laser,etc) is one of the most effective therapy and it is not known by anyone, it is proved by medical research not pseudoscience ...link : http://placenta-anticancer.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Brain-stimulation-potential.pdf  ;  it could brings 20 % another stem cell activated - patent with https://drprpusa.com/product/drprp-led-cell-activator/

Comment: Another Japanese study with infrared light for neurodegenerative disease  https://www.oatext.com/Infrared-light-as-a-potential-therapeutic-approach-for-neurodegeneration.php

Comment: No point asking for it to be "affordable" if you don't say what you can afford.

Comment: 60-80 dollars .I think. But you can mention what you find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um that's **really** not the way a screen works....

A typical mobile phone screen is an OLED panel, with red green and blue oleds, you cannot control the wavelength other then by varying the power of each of these three diodes that actually radiate whatever spectrum they radiate. Certainly you cannot decide that you want energy at xxxnm and make the screen produce it.

In particular notice that there is NO WAY to make yellow light, but you can fool the human eye because human vision is (kind of, sort of) tristimulus rather then actually being particularly sensitive to wavelength as such.

Surely you played with a prism in school? You might find one instructive, or possibly a diffraction grating? You will find that a mobile phone screen, looks a LOT like an RGB led in terms of spectrum.

There is a graph on the second to last page of this paper that shows a fairly typical OLED emission spectra for the red, green and blue elements (Of an OLED telly, but phones are pretty similar).

http://set.org.br/ijbe/ed2/06_IEEE%20format%20-%20Photometric%20and%20Colorimetric%20Comparison%20of%20OLED,%20NANOSP,%20and%20LCD.pdf

Comment: Dear Dan Mills . Thanks for clarifying. can you mention an affordable device for measuring optical power [mW]  of LED s ? Mention few choices and one for build if it is possible for range 400-700 nm . Thanks